# SIP auth with ejabberd

Tags: sip, ejabberd, opensips

I am trying to relay a SIP SUBSCRIBE message from OpenSIPS to my ejabberd server. However ejabberd insists on challenging this with a 407 Proxy Authentication Required response.

I would like to somehow add my OpenSIPs server as a trusted peer on ejabberd - is this possible at all? I've been playing with the acls and various parts of configuration but nothing seems to do the trick.

Pete